# Node Chat Server: Only the first computer sees everyone

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

the first computer is able to see a log of everyone coming into the room, but the new computers don't see what happened beforehand.

[server](https://github.com/mrtunes/websocket-relay-server/blob/master/index.js)

```
    var clientMessages = {};

socket.on("message", function (data) {
  var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
console.log("parsed id " + parsed.id);
    if (parsed.type === "join") {
        // A new client has joined.
        // First, send them all the changes for all the current synths that are in the chat.
         var jsonstringy = JSON.stringify({ type: "history", value: clientMessages});
         socket.send(jsonstringy);


        // Now create a new record to store all changes sent to this synth.
       clientMessages[parsed.id] = [parsed];
       console.log(clientMessages);
    } else if (parsed.type === "leave") {
        delete clientMessages[parsed.id];
    } else {
    clientMessages[parsed.id].push(parsed);
    }
});
```

the line which says push(parsed); sometimes throws an error and crashes the server.

the front end is located [here](https://github.com/mrtunes/websocket-relay-server/blob/master/web/synthRoom.html#l43).

Answer (score 0):

You're only sending data to the socket that received the message; you need to do a broadcast to all sockets, the syntax is:

```
var srv = require('http').createServer().listen(8080);
var io  = require('socket.io')(srv);

function sendToAll(topic, data) {
  io.sockets.in(topic).emit(topic, data); // <-- this sends the data to all sockets subscribed to the topic
}
```

When you receive a message, remember to subscribe the socket to the topic/message:

```
socket.join(topic);
```

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. i'm not using socket.io though. i will try to join the message.ids and then send them to new clients